# Rotate 2D list by 90 degrees or alternatively a method to get a specific column in 2D list

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a 2D list like so:

```
type Board = List[List[Option[Move]]]
```

looking a bit like this:

```
None None Some(X)
None None None
None None None
```

I can do things to row using the usual collection methods, map, fold etc. But I want to be able to operate on the columns in a similar fashion. I've been trying for about 1 hr with no luck (mindblank) for a method like so:

```
def getColumn(board: Board, column: Int): List[Option[Move]]
```

Given the above array, calling `getColumn(board, 2)`, I should receive `List(None, None, Some(X))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for is List.transpose. This will essentially rotate the list such that all of the columns will be grouped together. So your method could be:

```
def getColumn(board: Board, column: Int): List[Option[Move]] = board.transpose.apply(column)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ryan's answer is correct, and also preferred.  I experimented for a few minutes without realizing that "transpose" existed. Here is my non built-in approach:

```scala
def getColumn(board: Board, column: Int): List[Option[Move]] =
  for { r <- board } yield r(column)
```

2012/12/23 - updated to reflect @dhg comments

Comment: The inner for-loop is entirely unnecessary; it's just unwrapping, then re-wrapping the Option.  You should just do `for { r <- board } yield r(column)`

Comment: Why is Ryan's answer correct and preferred - why create a whole transposed board only to discard most of it? Your answer is better IMO. You can write it more simply as `board.map(_(column))`.

Comment: I would say that it is generally preferred to use built-ins over hand rolled code.  If this was a commonly executed piece of code it could be optimized by creating a transpose one time.  A Vector is probably a better data structure for this instead of List because of the indexed based access.